# grep a pattern and return all characters before and after another specific character bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl

I'm interested in searching a variable inside a log file, in case the search returns something then I wish for all entries before the variable until the character '{' is met and after the pattern until the character '}' is met.

To be more precise let's take the following example:

```
something something {
    entry 1
    entry 2
    name foo
    entry 3
    entry 4
}
something something test
test1 test2
test3 test4
```

In this case I would search for 'name foo' which will be stored in a variable (which I create before in a separate part) and the expected output would be:

```
{
        entry 1
        entry 2
        name foo
        entry 3
        entry 4
}
```

I tried finding something on grep, awk or sed. I was able to only come up with options for finding the pattern and then return all lines until '}' is met, however I can't find a suitable solution for the lines before the pattern.

I found a regex in Perl that could be used but I'm not able to use the variable, in case I switch the variable with 'foo' then I will have output.

```
grep -Poz '.*(?s)\{[^}]*name\tfoo.*?\}'
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the issue is you have a good pattern that should include a variable, but you're not able to add the variable into the grep command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an Awk attempt which tries to read between the lines to articulate an actual requirement.  What I'm guessing you are trying to say is that "if there is an opening brace, print all content between it and the closing brace in case of a match inside the braces. Otherwise, just print the matching line."

We accomplish this by creating a state variable in Awk which keeps track of whether you are in a brace context or not.  This simple implementation will not handle nested braces correctly; if that's your requirement, maybe post a new and better question with your *actual* requirements.

```sh
awk -v search="foo" 'n { context[++n] = $0 }
    /{/ { delete context; n=0; matched=0; context[++n] = $0 }
    /}/ && n { if (matched) for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print context[i];
        delete context; n=0 }
    $0 ~ search { if(n) matched=1; else print }' file
```

The variable `n` is the number of lines in the collected array `context`; when it is zero, we are not in a context between braces.  If we find a match and are collecting lines into `context`, defer printing until we have collected the whole `context`.  Otherwise, just print the current line.

Answer (score 5):

The regex is quite simple, once the whole file is read into a variable

```
use warnings;
use strict; 
use feature 'say';

die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if not @ARGV;

my $file_content = do { local $/; <> };  # "slurp" file with given name

my $target = qr{name foo};

while ( $file_content =~ /({ .*? $target .*? })/gsx ) { 
    say $1; 
}
```

Since we `undef`-ine the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) inside the [do](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do) block using [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Temporary-Values-via-local%28%29), the following read via the [null filehandle `<>`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) pulls the whole file at once, as a string ("slurps" it).  That is returned by the `do` block and assigned to the variable. The `<>` reads from file(s) with names in `@ARGV`, so what was submitted on the command-line at program's invocation.

In the regex pattern, the `?` quantifier makes `.*` match only up to the first occurrence of the next subpattern, so after `{` the `.*?` matches up to the first (evaluated) `$target`, then the `$target` is matched, then `.*?` matches eveyrthing up to the first `}`.  All that is captured by enclosing `()` and is thus later available in `$1`.

The `/s` modifier makes `.` match newlines, what it normally doesn't, what is necessary in order to match patterns that span multiple lines. With the `/g` modifier it keeps going through the string searching for all such matches. With `/x` whitespace isn't matched so we can spread out the pattern for readability (even over lines -- and use comments!).

The `$target` is compiled as a proper regex pattern using the [qr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) operator.

See regex tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut), and then there's the full reference [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut).